# Execute something by clicking object

Tags: python

This is probably a no-brainer, but somehow I can't find the solution with google. How do I execute a function **once**, if an object is clicked?

```
import bpy

def something(obj)
  print(obj.name)
  return

...
if anyObjClicked:
  something(context.scene.active_object)
```

Result should be:

```
Cube
```

and not

```
Cube
Cube
Cube
Cube
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's event system doesn't expose an event that triggers just once when an Object is selected (December 2015) - You aren't missing anything obvious.

You could make an event handler that listens for scene updates and only fires a custom function call once if the active_object changes between calls (these scene updates can be high frequency, 30 times per second).

read: [bpy.app.handlers.html](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html)  see `bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre` (or `..._post`)

The docs have sample code which you can extrapolate.

*ps*. this assumes your use case doesn't include clicking the same object a number of times in sequence.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The idea of monitoring the active object for a change is the solution for me! I'll figure the rest with some boolean triggers. Thank you!